# Can I specify default labels to apply to bigquery jobs?

Tags: google-bigquery

We have end users issuing queries against our bigquery tables from multiple places. From BI tools, from the GCP console, from bash scripts that use `bq`, from python scripts that call the API etc … we would like to be able to track the cost of queries so we can compare the cost of those different querying methods.

Within GCP the way to differentiate costs is to put labels onto stuff. Is there a way to mandate the labels that queries from any (all??) of those querying mechanisms must have? I think this is impossible for ad hoc bash/python scripts but perhaps we can mandate that a particular BI tool must pass through labels on all the queries that it issues.

Any advice on this subject would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can Mandate lables . But you can create seprate service accounts

- One  for CLI
- One for GCP console
- One  for BI
  and track your costs based on that.

Comment: Yes, that might provide some value but the service account doesn't come through in the GCP costs so doesn't provide value where I need it unfortunately.

Comment: Each service account can be connected to a seprate placeholder project and user will access other projects and table through it. That way you will get the cost segregation.